# itertools permutations and combinations

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I am struggling with using itertools permutations and combinations together.  Ultimately, I am trying to create a matrix of possible combinations of Customers across various permutations of machines. I believe I have the combinations piece, but have not been able to add permutations to the script.

Here's my code so far:

```
import itertools

Mach = [1,2,3,4]
Cust = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

a = len(Cust)

for n in range(a):
    print list(itertools.combinations(Cust,n))
    n = n+1
```

Ideally, I would like to solve all possible outputs of:

```
1 - 1,2,3
2 - 4,5,6
3 - 7,8,9
4 - 10,11,12
```

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Update:
Forgive my ignorance, using Product is not necessarily providing the results that I was driving towards.  What am I trying to do is create a list of Customers on Machines, with each Customer only reflected on one machine (at a time), and then iteratively creating another matrix of this combination; for all possible combinations.  I believe this is a combination, not a permutation problem, as for the output, I do consider 1: 1, 2, 3 and 1: 3, 2, 1 to be the same.

Example:
(Cust1, Mach1); (Cust2, Mach1); (Cust3, Mach2); (Cust4, Mach2); (Cust5, Mach2); (Cust6, Mach3); (Cust7, Mach3); (Cust8, Mach3); (Cust9, Mach3); (Cust10, Mach3); (Cust11, Mach4); (Cust12, Mach4)

Followed by (as an example):
(Cust1, Mach1); (Cust2, Mach2); (Cust3, Mach2); (Cust4, Mach2); (Cust5, Mach2); (Cust6, Mach3); (Cust7, Mach3); (Cust8, Mach3); (Cust9, Mach3); (Cust10, Mach4); (Cust11, Mach4); (Cust12, Mach4)

etc...

Comment: Note, `n = n+1` does absolutely nothing useful

Comment: You seem to want `itertools.product(Mach, Cust)`

Comment: what is your expected result? or what might you expect the result to look like ... the output table, or something else?

Comment: Dave, my expected result is all possible combinations of the various customers across the individual machines that I can then map the specific requirements to machine constraints for analysis for best fit.  My thoughts are more of a brute force approach to optimization for waste (defined by overall utilization of the deckle of the machine).

Comment: Juanpa - thanks for the feedback, guess I was thinking of other loop types and did not realize it was not needed

Comment: I am using Python 2 (2.7)

Comment: @mb12 For your output, do you consider 1: 1, 2, 3 and 1: 3, 2, 1 to be the same?

Comment: I do consider these to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `product` nor `combinations` is really what you want. You want to pair each item of `Mach` with a *set* of items from `Cust`.

```
n = len(cust)/len(m)
for i, m in enumerate(mach):
    print(m, cust[n*i: n*(i+1)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and insight.  Below is the end result I was looking for:

Comment: import itertools

Mach = [1,2,3,4]
Cust = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

a = len(Cust)

for n in range(a):
    print list(itertools.product(Mach,itertools.combinations(Cust,n)))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution which uses `itertools.combination`. The idea is to choose the combination for the first machine and then recursively generate combinations for the remaining customers and machines.

This solution was developped in Python3, but should work for Python2.

### Code

```
import itertools

def group_combinations(machines, customers):
    if not machines:
        yield {}
    else:
        for group in itertools.combinations(customers, len(customers) // len(machines)):
            remaining = [c for c in customers if c not in group]
            for others in group_combinations(machines[1:], remaining):
                arrangement = {machines[0]: group}
                arrangement.update(others)
                yield arrangement
```

### Example

```
machines = [1, 2]
customers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
groups = group_combinations(machines, customers)

for comb in groups:
    print(comb)
```

### Output

```
{1: (1, 2), 2: (3, 4)}
{1: (1, 3), 2: (2, 4)}
{1: (1, 4), 2: (2, 3)}
{1: (2, 3), 2: (1, 4)}
{1: (2, 4), 2: (1, 3)}
{1: (3, 4), 2: (1, 2)}
```